# How do you create an EWF UI page that modifies data when the user clicks a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-web-library

I want to make a page that collects some information from the user and then modifies the database if the user clicks a button. If the user navigates away from the page without clicking the button, I don't want anything to be modified.

How do I do this without having to manually put my own button in the content area?

Comment: Do you really need 3 new tags for this question?  Surely there must be *some* existing tag that you can use.

Comment: The library is built on top of ASP.NET, so we could tag it with that if it helps people.

Comment: What is this question even about?  Can we get a Google link to the thing you're discussing, please?  I can't find any concrete thing called "Enterprise Web Framework" or "Enterprise Web Library", and am hesitant to think that this one and only question about it on the internet requires *three* tags on it's own...

Comment: http://enterpriseweblibrary.org/. It's new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call EwfUiStatics.SetContentFootActions from LoadData of the page. This will cause a big button to be displayed in the lower right corner of the page. If the user clicks it, the data modification that you passed to the method will be executed.